# Windows commands inside WSL hang a very long time

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, windows-11

### wsl --version

WSL version： 0.60.0.0
kernel version： 5.10.102.1
WSLg version： 1.0.34
MSRDC version： 1.2.2924
Direct3D version： 1.601.0
DXCore version： 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version： 10.0.22621.160

### Distro Version

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

This issue is found when I upgrade my windows to 10.0.22621.160

### Reproduce steps:

- execute "wsl.exe --version"  (a windows command)
  --> the console output the result and **frozen for dozens of seconds** that I can't input next command.
- execute "wsl.exe --version | cat"  (windows command with pipe)
  --> the console output the result and ready for next command normally.
- execute "uname -a"  (a native linux command)
  --> the console output the result and ready for next command normally.
- execute "wsl.exe --version > /proc/self/fd/1 (pipe to standard output)
  --> same as "wsl.exe --version", the console will frozen dozens of seconds

So I think there must be something wrong with the standard output for windows command running in WSL session.

PS: I've raised a case to microsoft feedback hub and the github.
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8544
https://aka.ms/AAhd1ld